# Posting part of viewModel to post action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to know if I am doing something wrong or it is not possible to post only part of view model using default model binder. Let's say I have a complex viewmodel that only small part it should be posted. I would like to achieve something like this:

```
public class ComplexViewModel
{
    public object FirstNotPostedData { get; set; }
    public object SecondNotPostedData { get; set; }
    //......
    public object NthNotPostedData { get; set; }

    public InnerModelToPost InnerModelToPost { get; set; }
}

public class InnerModelToPost
{
    public string FirstProperty { get; set; }
    public string SecondProperty { get; set; }
    public string ThirdProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In view I would like to display part of model and post the other part:

```
@model ComplexViewModel
@* DISPLAYING DATA *@
<form>
    @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.InnerModelToPost.FirstProperty )
    @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.InnerModelToPost.SecondProperty )
    @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.InnerModelToPost.ThirdProperty )

    <button type="submit">Submit button</button>
</form>
```

And then I would like to be able to pass this model to my controller in this way using default model binder:

```
public ActionResult GetOnlyImportantPartOfModel( InnerModelToPost innermodel)
{
    //I'm getting empty model when I' doing like this

    return View();
}
```

You may ask why not to pass entire model as parameter to this action method. So the answer is: code readablity. I store ComplexViewModel in session and I read it in first line of my action method. I would like to pass only this data that I want to update my model with.

Comment: Why using plain `<form>` tag without declaring what action as submit target? Use `Html.BeginForm("GetOnlyImportantPartOfModel")` instead.

Comment: "I would like to know if I am doing something wrong" - depends; are you getting errors in your ajax request? How are you building your form data when making the ajax request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your need to use the `Prefix` property of `[Bind]` attribute to strip the `InnerModelToPost` prefix from your form values.

```
public ActionResult GetOnlyImportantPartOfModel([Bind(Prefix = "InnerModelToPost")] InnerModelToPost innermodel)
{
    ....
}
```

Having said that, if your only using properties of `InnerModelToPost`, then in your GET method, you can read the parent class (`ComplexViewModel`) from `Session`, but pass only the `InnerModelToPost` property to the view

Comment: Thank you, that is excacly what I was looking for

Comment: I also assume that is not your real form (it would be absurd to create a form containing non-editable form controls and them post it all back again unchanged)

Comment: Yes, that is made up example, I use jquery to update my hidden fields before I post form